# VirtualBox: "Warning: Connection timeout" when trying to run Laravel Homestead VM or x64 VMs

Tags: laravel-4, 64-bit, ubuntu-12.04, vagrant, virtualbox

Trying to solve my problem I did the next:

1. Added 'Ubuntu_64' to config file.
2. Switched my WiFi off (saw this solution at Laravel forums) before 'vagrant up' execution.
3. Enabled GUI.
4. Rolled the VirtualBox and its extension back (also from Laravel forums).

The VMs which were successfully run with Vagrant are the Debian Wheezy 7.5 x32 built with puphpet and precise32. 
As we can see, only x32 VMs could be run on my machine. I don't know why.

Here is my machine info:

- OS: Ubuntu 12.04 64
- Processor: AMD A8-4500M, 2 cores
- Virtualization is enabled in BIOS. See screenshot similar to my BIOS view: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncxPz.jpg)
- The latest Vagrant, VirtualBox and VirtualBox Extensions pack are installed
- my user is added to virtualbox group

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, your question helped me to fix my problem! 
I was getting this connection timeout, turned my wifi off and bam! All working fine!

Double check if your ubuntu is really 64 bit.
I got some problems with some linux architectures for AMD in the pest!
There are a few and sometimes they can be a headache.. I think I got this problem with centos, it was i686 instead of simple x64. I don't really know the difference but what you can try doing is:

Instead of adding the homestead box (vagrant box add laravel/homestead)
Why dont you try adding a simple ubuntu-32 machine and then you run vagrant up.

I dont really know if it's going to work, but it's worth trying!

Thanks again for your answer, it really helped me

Comment: Hi, @Magus. You know, its very strange, but the reason was in BIOS. Its  quite interesting, because there is an **inversion** in the BIOS: "Enabled" for Virtualization Technology means "Disabled", and "Disabled" means "Enabled". Its Lenovo Edge E545.

Comment: Ohhh man.. that's really something. Maybe it's a lenovo bug! In my older PC I had to turn it on and it was coherent! Now I got a mac and it comes enabled by default... Really weird! But I guess it will help somebody out! Thanks for the info though!